# How to crawl data from yelp.com without block our IP

Tags: node.js

I am using node packages of cheerio and nightmare for crawling from " Yelp.com ". I am retrieved data from Yelp.com.
But yelp has blocked my IP.
Please any one can provide solution or suggestions.Thanks in advance

Here is my code

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var fs        = require('fs');
var http      = require('http');
var cheerio   = require('cheerio');
var request   = require('request');

function yelpmenuitemsscrap(url)
{
   // console.log(url);

 var menuitems = new Nightmare();

 menuitems.goto(url);
 menuitems.wait();

 menuitems.evaluate(function () {
    var objs = [];
    $('div.menu-sections div.media-block.menu-  
     item').each(function(index){

        objs.push( $(this).find('div.media-story h4').text().trim());

    });
    return objs;
   },function (html) {});
   menuitems.run(function(err, nightmare) {
    if (err) 
    {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    else
    {
        console.log(nightmare);
    };


  });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

IP block is done because all the requests are being generated from the same server IP address which appears to be a hack attack on the server. In such requirements the data crawl should be done from the clients who are accessing the applications from different IP addresses. This will generate the traffic from different IP addresses and Yelp will not block it.

The other option is to use multiple HTTP Proxy servers which generate requests from all the different servers randomly so as not to block any specific IP address.

Another option is to use something like http://www.screen-scraper.com

Comment: There are off the shelf software tools available to create proxy servers and use them online for your requirements. Do some google search on "software proxy servers" and you will fine which matches your requirements.

Comment: I have tried someways to create multiple proxy servers.But I didn't get. Could you please provide me sample code for creating proxy server and its usage

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion